# Vue and vue-multiselect. Making Options to react to selected language

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-multiselect

I am currently working on a Vue-Website that supports multiple languages. The selected Language is stored in a vuex-store and i have the the computed property lang like this

```
lang(){
  return this.$store.state.lang
}
```

Now i use this property in v-ifs, shows, in other computed properties and so and it works pretty well. Theres only one thing where i run into problems and that's the multiselect (https://vue-multiselect.js.org/). the computed options property looks somthing like this

```
mappedOptions(){
  return this.options.map(
    (o, ind) => {
      return {name: o.title[this.lang], code: ind}
    }
  );
}
```

Now the problem is, that this does not work. Probably the options are being initialized in the created lifecycle hook and therefore are not beeing updated later on. Do you have any clever ideas how I could use multiple languages with this vue-multiselect? I pretty much like the component apart from this issue so I would not like to switch.

Comment: BTW "this does not work" isn't useful for troubleshooting. Without being able to see the options variable, the only things that stands out is `o.title[this.lang]` doesn't look right. Are you sure `o.title` is an object with keys matching `lang`?

Comment: yes. the keys are right. it also renders right on creation just changing the state in the vuex store of the language then doesn't update the multiselect

Comment: OK. A couple things to try: 1. Add some dummy code into your `mappedOptions()` to rule out some bug with map(): `let x = this.lang; console.log(x);` and 2. also try switch mappedOptions to a method. By switching to a method it will run much more frequently (as it won't have the computed magic), but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `v-if="computedOption"` on the multiselect, should solve the issue

Comment: thanks. no access to my computer right now, but will test it right away later